# FbGraph cannot update status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I wrote a Rails application. I used omniauth for authentication. 
session.rb

```
auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
```

Everything seems normal as well, but when I want to change my facebook status, fbgraph cannot do that. I wrote this code

```
provider = User.find_by_provider_and_name('facebook', current_user.name)
          @facebook = FbGraph::User.me(provider.token)
          @facebook.feed!("loanminder-test-message-#{Time.now.utc}")
```

And the exception is like that

> FbGraph::InvalidToken in LoansController#show
>
> OAuthException :: Error validating access token: Session does not
>   match current stored session. This may be because the user changed the
>   password since the time the session was created or Facebook has
>   changed the session for security reasons.

How can I solve the problem, how can I change my status via Rails?

Answer (score 2):

Your stored token is no longer being accepted. You will need to prompt the user to login again and use a new access token, or use the following token

`app_id|secret`

where if your app ID is 942523352 and your secret is bc76876876f67676ae0 then you access token is

`942523352|bc76876876f67676ae0`